# Why is CSSArrowPlease not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use [CSS Arrow Please](http://cssarrowplease.com/) to generate a border with an arrow pointing to the right. However it's not working, only the border is showing and I'm not exactly sure why. Any ideas? P.S. I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.95

**EDIT**: Link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFFQc/3/)

CSS

```
.green {
position: relative;
background: #none;
border: 4px solid green;
}
.green:after, .green:before {
left: 100%;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
}

.green:after {
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-left-color: #none;
border-width: 30px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -30px;
}

.green:before {
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-left-color: green;
border-width: 36px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -36px;
}
```

The object I'm giving a class of ".green"

```
<%= image_tag(step.o_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "green") %>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your code please?

Comment: there is no color `#none`. I think you want `none` without the `#`.

Comment: Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GFFQc/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your image in a div and apply the class to the div.